# Xcode won't run on device after deleting app

Tags: xcode

For some reason Xcode was running an old version of my app on the device. To fix it I deleted the app on my device after trying to reboot everyone. Now Xcode won't run on the device giving me:

error: failed to launch
No such file or directory (/Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Foo-ebesorzwidboecgphqwmmzabjvoe/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Foo.app/Foo)

EDIT - I added the directory. It is a directory on my Mac. Why would deleting the app from the iphone cause this?

EDIT2 - and its lying because the app is there. Runs fine on simulator.

EDIT3 For those following, or if someone wants to help out:

What is happening is I am changing the version number of the app. At this point it will no longer load the new version number onto the device. So I go to organizer/apps and delete all apps on the device. Then I rerun and get the above error. Restoring the iPhone from scratch is the only way to fix it.

Comment: Reboot the computer and iphone/ipad, then do a "Clean" of your xcode project and after the clean, "Build"/"Run" and it should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None of the standard reboot everything worked, but after restoring my iPhone as a new phone and NOT going from backup I was able to get it working.